# Kotlin-Null Safety

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-null-safety

Well...the question is --> **"Write a program to check for the null value of the variables x and y using 'Elvis' operator and '!!' operator. Need to complete the function nullable. It should return the length of the string if it is not null, otherwise -1"**

```
fun nullable(nullableString: String?): Int {
   

}
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
   val str = readLine()!!
    var result = -100
    if(str=="null") {
        result = nullable(null)
    }else
        result = nullable(str)
    println(result)
}
```

Comment: It would also help if you told us what you don't understand. Presumably this is homework or something and you're learning Kotlin? Have you looked at the [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html) on null safety? What have you tried?

Comment: Are you asking a homework question? If so, please update your question to include more information, as discussed here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4161471

Comment: The aim is to create a function named 'nullable' which will accept a nullable String as a parameter and returns the length of the string if it is not null, -1 otherwise...need the solution for this...the user input will be stored in the variable 'str'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fun nullable(nullableString: String?): Int {
  return nullableString?.length ?: -1
}
```

Comment: This really works !!

Answer (score 1):

Basically just return the input length using the [*Elvis* operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html#elvis-operator) or `-1` if the input is `null`.

```kotlin
fun nullable(nullableString: String?): Int = nullableString?.length ?: -1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fun nullable(nullableString: String?, default: Int): Int {
    return nullableString?.toIntOrNull() ?: default
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val str = readlnOrNull()
    val result = -1
    println(nullable(str, result))
}
```

Here 'str' variable accepts value while the default is -1 it returns default -1 or int value, this is with Elvis operator **but you want length instead of value** so here is the solution

```
fun nullable(nullableString: String?, default: Int): Int {
    return if (nullableString?.length == 0) {
        default
    } else { 
        nullableString?.length!! // !! is called the 'not-null assertion operator'
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val str = readlnOrNull()
    val result = -1
    println(nullable(str, result))
}
```